# Issues using a stored procedure and what to do next

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Update:

As suggested I will ask two separated questions with elaborated details.

This is probably a two-part question and maybe a common issue however I can’t figure it out.

We have a .net web service using Entity Framework with a code-first approach against a SQL Server 2012 (I think). We have a few tables some called `User`, `License`, `Product` etc..

We continually need to get data from the database regarding users, their licenses and products. For this data we execute a rather large stored procedure which accesses all the tables, do some processing and deliver the data e.g. the user with this userid have these licenses with these roles in relation to these products.

However, the execution of this stored procedure seems to regress over time and it becomes slower during the day. To prevent this, we run an optimization of the indexes every morning.

If the optimization is not executed every morning the stored procedure goes from 200ms execution time to 2000 ms execution time.

If anyone has insight to what is going on I would appreciate it. My knowledge of SQL and SQL Server is limited.

HOWEVER,

To avoid these issues regarding the stored procedure we have decided to rethink our strategy. For now, we have created a new table containing the key values from the others tables e.g. userid, license id, role, productid. However, this means we have to maintain this new table every time the other tables are altered.

So, my second part question is. Is a new table containing the key values which we can easily fetch a valid approach or should we do something completely else?

Comment: Make 2 separated questions. Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Also include relevant part of the store procedure

Answer (score 0):

The index is probably getting fragmented due to inserts or updates during the day. You could consider columnstore indexes. Try using SSMS query optimisation tool. Also consider hinting the query optimiser with loop joins if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to answer in a vacuum. You could van index problem with heavy inserts and i am guessing GUID as a key or you could have blocking issues due to heavy loads, you could have spills to tempdb due to low memory or old statistics etc. It's all guessing game. The best advise I can give you is hire professional, because one day you would have to, at list it is not going to be as bad as people without a clue thinking that they fixing stuff (because all devs are "smart"). 
At list get a consultation, because without looking at the issue, it is close to impossible to give you an answer. 
At the very list, you need to post a execution plan for your stored procedure.